# No persistence for 'App Folder' created in the Ubuntu's 'All apps' menu

Tags: 20.04, appmenu, logout

Recently I have reinstalled Ubuntu on my device. I grouped apps like libreOffice apps and Ubuntu games into 2 different folders in the Ubuntu's 'All apps' menu. But after I logged out and logged in again, I noticed the apps were not anymore grouped into 2 folders. To be clear about why I logged out, I was trying custom themes. I find this issue very weird and I can't find any solution to it. Can you help, if it can be resolved without re-installation of the OS ?